# Cordova Android Build

Tags: android, cordova, path

I am attempting to use the emulator via Phonegap, upon following [these instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) in order to build the app. It fist tells me that I dont have Android installed as a platform, but I do have the Android sdk, of which I then made sure that the path was correct [following these instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android), .

I then attempt to check platforms, and receive error that no platforms installed.

I then skipped to building the app, just to see what would happen, and receive this:

```
C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\hello>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4
\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PAT
fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-androi
age\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:159:19
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\co
d\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\.cordova\l
\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\.cor
_cache\cordova-android\3.6.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
    at C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-androi
age\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:821:14
    at flush (C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova
.4\package\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
Error: C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\.cordova\lib\npm_cache\cordova-androi
age\bin\create.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\Jessica.PORTER\AppData\Roamin
odules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:13
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Comment: "Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH" Check your environment / PATH variable.

Comment: How do I set Android Home? I edited path to the platform-tools and tools path....

Answer (score 0):

As you can still see from

```
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH
```

It clearly tells you that you haven't set the *ANDROID_HOME* and that the *android* command isn't found from your PATH. To fix it, locate the Android SDK installation location and at it to the PATH. Also, open new command line instance after adding them since they are only loaded at the boot-time of command line.

You can also check if the *android* command is correctly added to PATH by opening the command line and simply typing *android*. If it tells you something like *no such program*, it means that it isn't still available.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!! I have added the correct paths, I only had the platform-tools path, and I have now added the tools path, however it is still not working, returning with error......

Comment: Also, open new command line instance after adding them since they are only loaded at the boot-time of command line.        What does this mean exactly?

Comment: @JessicaClark: Sorry, I answered in a hurry. What I meant by opening a new command line instance was that, you need to open new command line every time you change the _PATH_ Unless you do that, the changes made for _PATH_ don't affect. Did you try to open new command line window and write _android_ there?

Answer (score 0):

Changing ANdroid Home -

I fixed the problem by adding a new Environment Variable named ANDROID_SDK_HOME and then linked it to Android folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Android

Thank you for all your help!!!!